# Jenkins pipeline - function to remove properly a folder

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I need to implement a function in groovy (for a Jenkins pipeline) which will remove a specific folder into a linux server.

```
def remove_folder(String path_of_the_folder) {
    sh "rm -rf <root_path>/${path_of_the_folder}"
}
```

It's pretty easy. But if the parameter is "" or " " or "/" or "." or "//" or... this will delete the <root_path> and it's absolutely critical.

How I can assure that will not happen ?

Thanks

Comment: `rm - rf ./path/to/folder` or `rm -rf ${WORKSPACE}/path/to/folder`. See [Pipeline variables](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables). Or just test the variable [is set](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) and [not root](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html) before proceeding.

Comment: Hello
How I can be sure that is not the root folder ? That root_path/path_of_the_folder is not root_path eventually ?

Comment: `[[ ${ROOT_PATH} != "/" && -d ${ROOT_PATH}/${path_of_the_folder} ]] && rm -fR ${ROOT_PATH}/${path_of_the_folder}`